# How can I use a laptop pointing stick for scrolling up/down?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad

My laptop has a touchpad but it's not multi-touch so I cannot use it to scroll up/down with two finger gestures. I was wondering if I could use the "pointing stick" in the keyboard to do the scrolling instead of using it also as a normal mouse. Is this possible to configure in such way with a Dell Latitude E6430 (2013) under Windows 7?

I tried updating the drivers by going to the Synaptics webpage, downloading and installing them, restarting the computer and trying again to configure the multitouch, but the option is not available in the Control Panel -> Mouse -> Synaptics configuration menu. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your laptop make and model?

Comment: added make and model